# Bootstrapping from an empirical distribution in R

Tags: r

If I'm given a set of data, I know how to use boot in R estimate the ci for some measure of the data. However, what if I'm given an empirical distribution based on the data, but not the data itself. Is it still possible to get ci on a measure?

To be specific, I am working with losses due to hurricanes. Rather than getting a set of hurricane losses, I have a function that models the losses.

```
Loss    P(Loss)
100        x
200        y
300        z
 .
 .
 .
```

So I can easily determine a 95% loss value -- sum P(loss) until it reaches 95% and then look at the value in the Loss column.

But how do I estimate a ci for this value? Is this possible in R?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the empirical distribution, why would you need to use bootstrapping for computing the confidence interval?

Comment: I have an empirical loss PDF.  I have no information on losses other than this PDF. We assign capital based on the 95% loss value.  I would like to have a range rather than a point estimate for this value.    One thought I had was to generate a large number of random #s from an uniform normal, invert the CDF, calculate 95% and repeat 1000 time to get distribution on the 95% value. I thought `boot` might be a better way